# How to wrap AutoGeneratedColumn headers in a TextBlock from code-behind?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a DataGrid completely in code-behind as the whole GUI is dynamically generated.

I have stumbled upon a problem whereby the headers in my dataGrid do not display underscores.  I have thus read that wrapping the headers in TextBlocks will solve this problem.

However, my DataGrid's source is a DataTable, and I am not sure how to go about wrapping the headers of the columns in a TextBlock since everything is auto-generated.

This is my code:

```
DataGrid dgResults = new DataGrid();
dgResults.IsReadOnly = true;
dgResults.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgResults.CanUserAddRows = false;
dgResults.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
dgResults.CanUserReorderColumns = false;
dgResults.CanUserResizeColumns = false;
dgResults.CanUserResizeRows = false;
dgResults.CanUserSortColumns = false;
dgResults.ItemsSource = dtResults.AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has a similar problem, I've solved it myself.  This can be handled in the DataGrid's OnColumnGenerating event.